# scanf behaving unexpectedly?

Tags: go

Below is my simple code, and whenever I try to enter role 'crack' on terminal, sometimes it takes it well, and sometimes it strangely takes it as 'Drack'. Why in the world would it do that? Its happening quite often

```
fmt.Println("\n Do you want crack a hash (type 'crack') or just help other nodes in cracking their hash (type 'help')?")
fmt.Scanf("%s\n", &role)
fmt.Println("role taken is", role)
if role == "crack" {
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show a bit more of your code. `role` declaration etc.

Comment: What OS are you using ? what terminal ? can you print the variable role in this way `fmt.Printf("role taken is %q", role)` ? ( **%q** is to show **q**uotes ) Also you don't need to include **\n** in your Scanf call, and for your example you can use just `fmt.Scan(&role)`

Answer (score -1):

This is maybe because you are using `\n` in `scanf` function instead of using `\n` in `scanf` try using it in succeeding `Println` statement as shown below:

```
fmt.Scanf("%s", &role)
fmt.Println("\nrole taken is", role)
```

Comment: that shouldnt make any difference? How will c be converted to D?

Comment: yes it should solve the problem because scanf function scan values and here you have passed new line escape sequence that is why behavior of the function is unexpected.
try running it now and see if you find same behavior again